# Making a visual studio project openable by anyone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've uploaded my c# MVC project to GitHub, however, from what I can see, you'll need to the same version of VS that I'm running in order to open the project.

Atleast the express version doesnt open it (atleast not withuot tweaking the GUIDs) - I'm running the ultimate version for VS 2013.

How can I make sure that anyone can download my project from GitHub and open it with their version of VS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with makefile instead of with Visual Studio projects. Makefiles are a lot more stable.

You could maintain several solutions and projects, and put the VS version in their names, `example.90.sln` for VS2008, `example.11.sln` for VS2012, `example.12.sln` for VS2013.

You could maintain just the lowest acceptable version, which will be automatically upgraded on each client's machine by its own Visual Studio. This is what I would do.